# How to refresh ComboBox data (Form-1), after updating Data Grid View Data(Form-2)

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

- ComboBox - Form 1
- DataGridView - Form 2

ComboBox is data-bound to "Quality Setup Table"

ComboBox: Display Members "Quality Code: 401, 402, 403 etc."

When I open Form 2 - (DataGridView), perform changes and Close.
new updated data doesn't reflect in ComboBox.

I have to close application and restart to see the newly added data in ComboBox.

What should I do to update ComboBox Data with Newly Added/Removed Data in Data Grid View after Closing Form 2.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **ComboBox.DataBind()** when you are updating DataGridView ?

I think you can Find the control from the form and invoke the DataBind() method to refresh the Items of the ComboBox. Hope this helps

Comment: but its already binded, otherwise the new data wont appear after restarting app, which means the comboBox is data bounded.

Comment: Yeah, But whenever the data is updated you can use the DataBind() method to **Re-Bind** data to the control.

Comment: Ok so it should go like this?
comboBox1.DataSource = TableAdapter.TableName;

and where should it go In form2_closed? 
or form1 initalize or form1_load?

Answer (score 0):

**I have found solution to my own problem.**
*In order to update ComboBox with New Data.*

Write this in form 1.

Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.showDialog(); // it must be show dialog only not show.

// below here write code that fills data into comboBox
// you can find this code in Form1_Load.
// once that is done. Your comboBox will begin updating data whenever Form2 Closes.